# How to make AWS Api Gateway deployment depend on dynamic list using Terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

When I generate resources, methods etc. using "for_each", how can I make a deployment depend on them? Terraform requires a static list as value for "depends_on"

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for here is this (somewhat hidden) reference in terraform documents about triggers

I was facing the same issue (using for_each to create gateway methods, integrations) but was not able to reliably trigger api-gateway redeployment, until this...

> ... or removing the .id references to calculate a hash against whole resources. Be aware that using whole resources will show a difference after the initial implementation. It will stabilize to only change when resources change afterwards

This allow us to do the following in triggers

```
triggers = {
redeployment = sha1(jsonencode([
  aws_api_gateway_resource.gateway_resources,
  aws_api_gateway_method.gateway_methods,
  aws_api_gateway_integration.gateway_integrations,
]))}
```

By removing .id (and thus not needing to reference each.key, or any element in the dynamic list) you let terraform decide if the hash of the file changed. If it did it will redeploy, if it doesnt change, then no redeploy required :)

Reference https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_deployment#terraform-resources

- Look at the comments on 'triggers'

Comment: The problem is that Terraform will often try to create the deployment before the integrations are ready, which will end in failure

Comment: Yeh, I think this is sometimes unavoidable as api-gateway deployments are not 'atomic' (at least from what I've seen. You could also add `depends_on` to ensure thats at least completed in the terraform.